# Custom File Drag-n-Drop

Tags: windows, winapi, drag-and-drop

How can I register a custom file drag-n-drop functionality to Windows Explorer?

E.g. when you grab a file and drop it from a folder to another while holding the alt key, it creates a shortcut to the file, or holding the shift key will move the files over to the destination.

What I am trying to achieve is to register a new key combination (say alt + control) or override an existing one. Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/449/The-Complete-Idiot-s-Guide-to-Writing-Shell-Extens

Comment: The drop target controls what happens when the item is dropped, not the drag source. (How would the drop target know what to if the user does a custom Alt+Ctrl drag?)